# Why is CodeIgniter producing "Call to undefined method" in model I've created?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

So I've been tasked with creating a function for our member database that will alert someone on a monthly basis as to when their membership is going to expire.  We send out one email if a person is 6 months or less from their membership expiration, and another if they are 3 months out.  No big whoop.  I first create a model like this:

```
class Email extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

// -----------------EMAIL-----------------
function emailMessage($message = 1,$recipient = 1777) { // Default "Test" Numbers
    $rInfo = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE intKey = " . $recipient)->row();
    $eInfo = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE intKey = " . $message)->row(); 

    // Replacements?
    $bodyCopy = $eInfo->txtEmail;
    $bodyCopy = str_replace("[firstname]",$rInfo->strFirstName,$bodyCopy);  

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('someone@example.com','John Q Public');
    $this->email->to($rInfo->strEmail); 
    $this->email->subject($eInfo->strTitle);
    $this->email->message($bodyCopy);
    $this->email->send();
    $this->email->clear();
}
}
```

All fine and good, and when I call this model from any other part of the site I have built, it works fine.  It's a great way to handle any stock emails that have to be sent out to our constituency.  Normally, it's just something like this within the code:

```
$this->load->model('email');
$this->email->emailMessage(8,$this->session->userdata('memberKey'));
```

Works like a charm.  The big difference between where I've used it previously, and where I use it now is that I'm enclosing the call to the model within a loop as follows:

```
public function warningEmails() {
    $this->load->model('email');
    $sql = 'SELECT
                *, FLOOR(
                    DATEDIFF(dtAccreditationEnd, now())/ 30
                )AS diff
            FROM
                tblMembers
            WHERE
                enmAccredited = "yes"
            AND dtAccreditationEnd < DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
            ORDER BY
                diff
    ';  
    $emailSend = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach ($emailSend->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->diff <= 3) {
            $letter = 10;
        } else {
            $letter = 9;
        }
        $this->email->emailMessage($letter,$row->intMembersKey);
    }
}
```

It works great the first time through the loop, and fails with the following message the very next iteration through the loop:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined method CI_Email::emailMessage() in **/home/contract/public_html/members/application/controllers/staff.php** on line **1033**

Line 1033 is this line:

```
  $this->email->emailMessage($letter,$row->intMembersKey);
```

I there a problem where this model can only be called once in a given instance?  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**EDIT:** I'm going to add a var_dump($this->email); to see what it could be...

> object(CI_Email)#30 (46) {   ["useragent"]=>   string(11)
>   "CodeIgniter"   ["mailpath"]=>   string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
>   ["protocol"]=>   string(4) "mail"   ["smtp_host"]=>   string(0) ""
>   ["smtp_user"]=>   string(0) ""   ["smtp_pass"]=>   string(0) ""
>   ["smtp_port"]=>   string(2) "25"   ["smtp_timeout"]=>   int(5)
>   ["smtp_crypto"]=>   string(0) ""   ["wordwrap"]=>   bool(true)
>   ["wrapchars"]=>   string(2) "76"   ["mailtype"]=>   string(4) "text"
>   ["charset"]=>   string(5) "utf-8"   ["multipart"]=>   string(5)
>   "mixed"   ["alt_message"]=>   string(0) ""   ["validate"]=>
>   bool(false)   ["priority"]=>   string(1) "3"   ["newline"]=>
>   string(1) " "   ["crlf"]=>   string(1) " "   ["send_multipart"]=>
>   bool(true)   ["bcc_batch_mode"]=>   bool(false)   ["bcc_batch_size"]=>
>   int(200)   ["_safe_mode"]=>   bool(false)   ["_subject"]=>   string(0)
>   ""   ["_body"]=>   string(357) "Geoffrey,
>
> This is a reminder that your PDCA Accreditation will expire in 3
>   months.   Visit your Membership Dashboard to view all complete and
>   incomplete course work at your convenience. The Membership Dashboard
>   will assist you through the completion process.     For more
>   information, please contact Someone at Someone@example.com or
>   1-800-555-1212."   ["_finalbody"]=>   string(0) ""
>   ["_alt_boundary"]=>   string(0) ""   ["_atc_boundary"]=>   string(0)
>   ""   ["_header_str"]=>   string(0) ""   ["_smtp_connect"]=>
>   string(0) ""   ["_encoding"]=>   string(4) "8bit"   ["_IP"]=>
>   bool(false)   ["_smtp_auth"]=>   bool(false)   ["_replyto_flag"]=>
>   bool(false)   ["_debug_msg"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["_recipients"]=>
>   string(17) "recipient@example.com"   ["_cc_array"]=>   array(0) {   } 
>   ["_bcc_array"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["_headers"]=>   array(5) {
>       ["From"]=>
>       string(54) ""Someone Example" "
>       ["Return-Path"]=>
>       string(28) ""
>       ["Cc"]=>
>       string(16) "copy@example.com"
>       ["Bcc"]=>
>       string(17) "blindcopy@example.com"
>       ["Subject"]=>
>       string(49) "=?utf-8?Q?PDCA_Accreditation_Expiration_Warning?="   }   ["_attach_name"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["_attach_type"]=>   array(0) { 
>   }   ["_attach_disp"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["_protocols"]=>   array(3)
>   {
>       [0]=>
>       string(4) "mail"
>       [1]=>
>       string(8) "sendmail"
>       [2]=>
>       string(4) "smtp"   }   ["_base_charsets"]=>   array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(8) "us-ascii"
>       [1]=>
>       string(9) "iso-2022-"   }   ["_bit_depths"]=>   array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(4) "7bit"
>       [1]=>
>       string(4) "8bit"   }   ["_priorities"]=>   array(5) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(11) "1 (Highest)"
>       [1]=>
>       string(8) "2 (High)"
>       [2]=>
>       string(10) "3 (Normal)"
>       [3]=>
>       string(7) "4 (Low)"
>       [4]=>
>       string(10) "5 (Lowest)"   } }

Comment: Really weird, try adding `var_dump($this->email);` in the loop and share the results (first time and the next iteration). BTW , the model name should be Uppercase (first letter) , like "Email".

Comment: OK... this is what I get from the `var_dump($this->email);` as follows:

Or at least... I'll put in the "Answer Your Question" because I don't have the length for it here in comments...

Comment: Or rather... add to what's up there!  Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the official email library to another one by doing so,

```
$this->load->library('email', NULL, 'ci_email');
```

Then access it by doing this,

```
$this->ci_email->from('someone@example.com','John Q Public');
```

The current email library has overwritten your email model.

Comment: That worked like a charm!  Thank you!  I didn't know there was a conflict in naming between libraries and models I've created.  I'll be more careful next time around!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar symptoms, but due to a different issue. I had recently changed my file names of my models from name_model.php to Name_model.php through my editor of choice, and little did I realize that my editor didn't actually remove the old name_model.php file, so two files were sitting in the directory with the same name and different case.

I was creating a new function in my model, but it was reading the old model file, which held me up for a good few hours until I took a peek at the actual files in the directory.

Simply removing the old files helped my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misreading this,  but doesn't this line:
   $this->load->library('email');

Load the email library in which this line is written?  I think you are recursively killing yourself.

Comment: Not exactly.  Because I have a "model" called email ... that pulls from a directory called "models" in codeIgniter.  This is different from the "library" folder... so you could have a model that calls a library.  Then again, I could be wrong.  Let me try renaming it and seeing what happens.  _(btw... is this Jeremy?  The chance of knowing two people with the same llama as an icon is not impossible, but improbable, yes?  Hello!)_

Comment: Indeed, you've found out my secret identity! ;D

Comment: I was wrong!  The post from "Burning the Codeigniter" above did the right thing.  I guess there IS a need for different names for "in the box" libraries and user generated "model"... it was recursion city!

Answer (score 0):

i could not get my library class MbSec{} loaded neither with autoload

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'mbsec');
```

or a load in the controller.

```
$this->load->library('mbsec');
```

but is seems to work with Capitals, isn't that against the logic?

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'MbSec');
```